# How many hits are necessary to perform each combo named in the game?

Tags: killer-instinct-2013

These are all the names of the combos (without need of ultra and ultimate combos), but I lack of knowledge as of how many you have to hit to achieve for the rest of them. At a certain point you need more hits to get certain combo name (eg. I guess for godlike 30 hits?).

```
Basic - 2 hits
Triple - 3
Quad - 4
Solid - 5
Hyper - 6
Brutal - 7
Master - 8
Blaster - 9
Extreme - 10
Awesome - ??..
Monster
Insane
Beastly
King
Crazy
Killer
Godlike
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of hits for each combo name seems to be as follows.

> BASIC: 2 hits
>   TRIPLE: 3
>   QUAD: 4
>   SOLID: 5
>   HYPER: 6
>   BRUTAL: 7
>   MASTER: 8
>   BLASTER: 9
>   EXTREME: 10-11
>   AWESOME: 12-13
>   MONSTER: 14-15
>   INSANE: 16-17
>   BEASTLY: 18-20
>   KING: 21-23
>   CRAZY: 24-26
>   KILLER: 27-29
>   GODLIKE: 30+

Source: http://www.gamefaqs.com/xboxone/718565-killer-instinct/faqs/70214